# i want to translate string in other language using angular translate, but how to use in javascript which has the notification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In below code i want to translate notification message in to another laguage, so how to translate, which dependency will require?

```
{
    window.history.back();
    $timeout(function(){
    Notification.info('Doubles Team not found. The Id is either wrong or the           Doubles Team has been deleted by the Admin.');//$state.go('error');
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking

Comment: I have a json file basically in html file we translate label or string as-  translate:"key" . but i have java script file in that there is having notification i.e.string, so i want to translate this string, so how to translate, what is syntax and is there is need  to add dependency in it

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) module.

Once you include it, you can store in a separate json file all your translation, for instance, you will have the file en.json containing:

```
{
   NO_DOUBLE_TEAM: "Doubles Team not found. The Id is either wrong or the Doubles Team has been deleted by the Admin;
}
```

And then in your controller, you add a dependency to the $filter service and you can do:

```
var infoUser = $filter('translate')('NO_DOUBLE_TEAM').
```

Depending on the language selected, it will display the good value.

There are plenty of tutorials for this module:

http://ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html

https://angularjs.de/artikel/angularjs-i18n-ng-translate

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need [angular-translate module](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate), include it in your app, afterwards you need to create json files for your languages.

```
{
NO_DOUBLE_TEAM: "Doubles Team not found. The Id is either wrong or the Doubles Team has been deleted by the Admin;
}
```

Then simply use it like this.

```
{
    window.history.back();
    $timeout(function(){
    Notification.info($translate.instant('NO_DOUBLE_TEAM'));//$state.go('error');
}
```